# Running Julia using a modern terminal such as Windows Terminal

Tags: powershell, julia, windows-terminal

I am a beginniner user of Julia. According to the webpage of the Julia Programming Language, "We highly recommend running Julia using a modern terminal, such as installing the Windows Terminal from the Microsoft Store" (Julia 1.6 for Windows). In fact, PowerShell handles the Julia fonts in a better way.

However, the installation of Julia generates a start menu item that runs under cmd as default. How can I create run Julia so that it uses PowerShell as default?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit**

The easiest solution is now to install Julia through the Windows Store, which is [Juliaup](https://github.com/JuliaLang/juliaup), and manages different versions of Julia easily

**My old answer (still valid)**

I don't know if it is possible

You can add your julia installation folder to the PATH so that `julia` opens julia in Powershell

Or, if you want to be able to have multiple versions and chose which one to launch, you can use PowerShell aliases in `$profile`:

```
New-Alias julia1.6.0 C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Julia-1.6.0\\bin\\julia.exe
New-Alias julia1.5.3 C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Julia-1.5.3\\bin\\julia.exe
New-Alias julia julia1.6.0
```

to see where it is and edit it:

```
echo $profile
notepad $profile
```

Answer (score 2):

I strongly recommend the Open Source [ConEmu](https://github.com/Maximus5/ConEmu).

Set your Windows Julia shortcut to (this assumes that the folder with `julia.exe` is in your system `PATH` environment variable):

```
"C:\Program Files\ConEmu\ConEmu64.exe" -run julia
```

you can not get better Windows user experience than that :-)

Comment: Works like charm. An additional julia command window is also opened.